# Python searching list thats inputted by user

Tags: python

Hi im trying to write a program which uses a repetition statement to allow users to enter 5 numbers and stores them in a list.Then allow the user to search the list for a number entered by the user and indicate whether the number has been   found or not. Im quite stuck on this one, I've made as much of an effort as i can

```
data =raw_input('Please input 5 numbers: ')
print data

search =raw_input('Search for the numer: ')
for sublist in data:
   if sublist[1] == search:
    print "Found it!", sublist
 break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this

```
numbers = []

while len(numbers) < 5:
    number = raw_input('Please input 5 numbers: ')
    if number.isdigit():
        numbers.append(int(number)) #may want to use float here instead of int
    else:
        print "You entered something that isn't a number"

search = raw_input('Search for the numer: ')
if int(search) in numbers:
    print "Found it!"
```

your code indicates that you may be using sublists but it is unclear how you are creating them.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a string, the `for` loop  will loop over every character in this string. That's probably not what you want.

If you want to find an integer in a list of integers, [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the input on whitespace and convert each to an integer using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

```
ints = [int(x) for x in data.split()]
if int(search) in ints:
    print "Found it"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**: This line stores the input as a string in the variable `data`.

```
data =raw_input('Please input 5 numbers: ')
```

At this point it is necessary to split the string into a list, and converting the elements to integers.
If the user inputs numbers separated by a space, you can do:

```
data_list = data.split() # if the numbers are comma-separated do .split(',') instead
int_list = [int(element) for element in data_list]
```

**Issue 2:** The users search input should be converted to an integer

```
search =raw_input('Search for the numer: ')
search_int = int(search)
```

**Issue 3:** There is no need for indexing the sublist as you've attempted `sublist[1]`.
The for-loop should then be:

```
for sublist in int_list:
    if sublist == search_int:
        print "Found it!", sublist
        break
```

Comment: If you convert the `search` into an `int`, but not the `data_list` - this will never work... also - you don't require an explicit for look and comparison... just using: `if search in data_list` will do it